# How to use Bootstrap dropdown.js as standalone?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to use the Bootstrap dropdown.js component without using the rest of the Bootstrap library? I've tried, but not managed to get it to work.

From the docs, I can see that the dropdown.js component requires Popper, and I can find the dropdown.js [src](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/js/src/dropdown.js) file on GitHub.

But it seems that dropdown.js has a lot of dependencies:

```
import * as Popper from '@popperjs/core'

import {
  defineJQueryPlugin,
  getElement,
  getElementFromSelector,
  isDisabled,
  isElement,
  isVisible,
  isRTL,
  noop,
  getNextActiveElement,
  typeCheckConfig
} from './util/index'
import EventHandler from './dom/event-handler'
import Manipulator from './dom/manipulator'
import SelectorEngine from './dom/selector-engine'
import BaseComponent from './base-component'
```

And I'm not sure what to do about these. I've tried removing them, but I just get error messages that variables later on in the file are undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really possible. Dropdown.js is built using functions inside of popper.js and the bootstrap library.

If you are looking for something outside of bootstrap for a dropdown, I would recommend [chosen.js](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) which uses jQuery. If you download the source files you can modify the css to style it more to your liking.

Outside of that, you can also make your own [vanilla javascript dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_dropdown.asp).

If you really love dropdown.js but need to have it standalone, you may use developer tools to reverse-engineer it and make your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this. Import Dropdown module and initialise it.

```
import { Dropdown } from "bootstrap";

var dropdownElementList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle'))
var dropdownList = dropdownElementList.map(function (dropdownToggleEl) {
    return new Dropdown(dropdownToggleEl)
})
```